# Javascript Efficient way of reassinging value of an empty variable

Tags: javascript, logic

Might of butchered that title , but anyway:

I have a form , and i want to change the value that is passed to my PHP file if the user enters nothing "" into the form value.

```
 var A = aFromForm.value;
 var B=  bFromForm.value;
 var C = cFromForm.value;


if (A ==="")
{
A = <?php echo $dbAvalue ?>;
}
if (B ==="")
{
B = <?php echo $dbBvalue ?>;
}
if (c ==="")
{
C = <?php echo $dbCvalue ?>;
}
```

However I cant write it like this because it needs to be if/else - however If I write 3 if else statements then it wont work in scenarios where more than one var is equal to "".

Apart from a tonne of if else statements, is there a better way to do this?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always use this pattern when I have a similar problem:

```
var A = aFromForm.value || '<?php echo $dbAvalue ?>';
```

Note that you need to wrap the php statement within quotes for it to be rendered as a JS string.

Comment: It probably would be a better idea to use `<?php echo json_encode($dbAvalue); ?>` (but even that won't make it absolutely safe)

Comment: Possibly, I don't use php. I think that the question is more about how to have a default for a variable than how to render safe JS

Comment: Indeed, I'm going to +1 but please add it as an alternative so that people could see a safer way to do that.

Comment: thanks , yeah im more concerned about having a default for a variable at the moment , however , in terms of the logic for your solution, how do I interpret it , traditionally I see this as A = B OR C

Comment: @Viktor in JS the `||` operator returns first [non-falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) value. Strictly speaking it's not a boolean operator.